# Speed up compilation time for Play 2.5/Activator/sbt on windows using IntelliJ

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, playframework, compilation

Here is the config:
Play 2.5
sbt 2.11.7
IntelliJ Community and Ultimate
Windows 7 with 8MB RAM and 700GB harddisk

"activator clean compile" is compiling 11 Scala sources and 1000 Java Sources. 
It takes an hour to do that on a windows machine. But takes less than 15 mins on a MAC book pro.

Any change to the code. Example: Just changed primitive int to a Wrapper Integer and it took close to 20 mins to compile on windows but takes few seconds on MAC.

Now, not everyone can afford to have mac.

Does anyone know whats the best way to get this fixed ?
I read a lot on this incremental compile for play and don't know if it is really of any use.

Comment: Are these 2 different computers? What is the hardware of each?

Comment: One is windows and other is Mac.
Windows is as follows: 
Intel Core i5
8MB RAM
Windows 7

MacBook Pro:
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 
OS X El Capitan

Comment: Does the windows pc have an SSD disk? It seems that the mac hardware is more powerful, so it might explain the time difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve compilation speed of Play Framework 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176440/how-to-improve-compilation-speed-of-play-framework-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I used to run my application through `Menu > Run > Run/Debug`, where I later figured out that I have to remove `Make` process. I removed `Make` step from the configuration - `Menu > Run > Edit Configurations`. After this change it looked fine and took less time to run.Yes, that makes things run faster.

But compiling the code first is the main point of running the tests while doing test driven development. It seems to be related to an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8183) in IDEA, where the Play Compiler is used, even though it is not selected, and this compiler spends time.

A workaround was described in the issue mentioned above.

1. Disable play2 compiler in settings
2. Delete the play*xml files in the .idea folder for your project
3. Restart IDEA
4. If you reimport the project (e.g. when build.sbt changes), you'll have to delete the xml files and restart IDEA again.

This would hopefully fix - check for updates in the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8183) tracker

Comment: I have tried on both Ultimate (Which supports Play2) and Community (Which does not support Play2) edition of IntelliJ. Both had same issues with compile time. Also, I have seen this work around earlier, but I dont see any play*xml file in .idea folder for my project.